# JMETER -> How to change the GMT time zone in jmeter.properties file

Tags: time, jmeter

When I use the Simple Data Writer and save responses to a file where the time is:

```
Date: Thu, 09 Aug 2018 15:13:51 GMT
```

I want to post the current timing which is 11 something i.e., this time - 4.

How to change this?

Comment: what's the value of `jmeter.save.saveservice.timestamp_format` in jmeter.properties file?

Answer (score 0):

If this `Date: Thu, 09 Aug 2018 15:13:51 GMT` is a part of your response and you need to change it on the fly you can do this using [JSR223 PostProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) and Groovy language.

The relevant code which will extract the date from the response, subtract 4 hours from it and replace the old date with the new date would be something like:

```
def response = prev.getResponseDataAsString()

log.info("Full response: " + response)

use(groovy.time.TimeCategory) {
    def detectedDate = (response =~ "Date: (.+) GMT")[0][1]
    Date oldDate = Date.parse("EE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss", detectedDate)
    Date newDate = oldDate - 4.hour
    log.info("Old date: " + oldDate)
    log.info("New date: " + newDate)
    response = response.replace(detectedDate, newDate.format("EE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss"))
    prev.setResponseData(response, "UTF-8")
}
```

Demo:

[image: JMeter Groovy Replace Response with another]

More information:

- [Groovy Goodness: Working with Dates](http://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2009/08/groovy-goodness-working-with-dates.html)
- [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)